# inequality for positive contraction operator

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, let $A\in B(H)$ satify $\|A\|\le 1$. If $A$ is positive, i.e. $A$ is a self-adjoint operator and for all $x\in H$, $\langle A(x),x\rangle\ge 0$, proof that 
$${\|x-A(x)\|}^2\le {\|x\|}^2-{\|A(x)\|}^2, \forall x\in H.$$
This is a exercise. For $A$ is positive
\begin{align*}
{\|x-A(x)\|}^2
&={\|x\|}^2+{\|A(x)\|}^2-\langle A(x),x\rangle-\langle x,A(x)\rangle\\
&={\|x\|}^2-{\|A(x)\|}^2+2{\|A(x)\|}^2-2\langle x,A(x)\rangle
\end{align*}
so we should prove that 
$${\|A(x)\|}^2\le \langle x,A(x)\rangle$$
or 
$${\|A(x)\|}^2=\langle A(x),A(x)\rangle = \langle x,A(A(x))\rangle \le \langle x,A(x)\rangle$$
but i don't know how to use the condition "$\|A\|\le 1$" and "$\langle A(x),x\rangle\ge 0$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $A$ is a positive operator, you can take it square root, which is also a positive operator, and
$$
\|A(x)\|^2 = \langle A^{1/2}A^{1/2}x,A x\rangle = \langle A^{1/2}x,A (A^{1/2}x)\rangle
$$
now by Cauchy-Schwarz and the fact that $\|A\|\leq 1$
$$
\langle A^{1/2}x,A (A^{1/2}x)\rangle ≤ \|A^{1/2}(x)\|\|A(A^{1/2}(x))\| ≤ \|A^{1/2}(x)\|^2 = \langle x, A(x)\rangle
$$
which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: I haven't studied the operator theorey, so i didn't know about square root of an operator before. Now i knew that, thank you so much!

Comment: If you don't know the square root, you perhaps have other possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

For an alternative solution which doesn't involve the square root, consider this. From $\|A\| \le 1$ it follows that for all $x \in H$ holds
$$\langle Ax,x\rangle \le \|Ax\|\|x\| \le \|x\|^2.$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
0 &\le \langle A(Ax-x),Ax-x\rangle \\
&= \langle A^2x - Ax, Ax - x\rangle\\
&= \underbrace{\langle A^2x,Ax\rangle}_{\le\|Ax\|^2} - \underbrace{\langle A^2x,x\rangle}_{=\|Ax\|^2} - \underbrace{\langle Ax,Ax\rangle}_{=\|Ax\|^2} + \langle Ax,x\rangle\\
&\le \langle Ax,x\rangle - \|Ax\|^2
\end{align}

so $\langle Ax,x\rangle \ge \|Ax\|^2$.

Comment: Why $\langle A^2x,Ax\rangle \le \langle Ax,x\rangle$?

Comment: @dapeng Sorry, I made a mistake. For any $x \in H$ we have $\langle Ax,x\rangle \le \|x\|^2$ so
$$\langle A^2x,Ax\rangle = \langle A(Ax),Ax\rangle \le \|Ax\|^2.$$
This gives the conclusion.

Comment: Thank you, i got it!

Comment: Great, I was sure there was a solution without the square root!